# Calculated Field Attempt not Working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column-formula

I am in a need to get a calculated field that will accommodate the following:

```
If Opp Type = Extension Renewal or On Contract Growth
AND
If TnC Change = No
AND
If Fin Pro = Yes
Then set value to Yes
```

I am using the following but it does not appear to be working:

```
=IF(AND(OR([Opp Type]="Extension Renewal",[Opp Type]="On Contract Growth"),[TnC Change]="No",[Fin Pro]="Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

> =IF(AND(AND(OR([Opp Type]="Extension Renewal",[Opp Type]="On Contract Growth"),[TnC Change]="No"),[Fin Pro]="Yes"),"Yes","No")

Try above formula where I assumed [Opp Type] as a single line of text, and [TnC Change] and [Fin Pro] as choice field.

Answer (score 0):

Use following formula:

```
IF(
    OR(
        [Opp Type]="Extension Renewal",
        [Opp Type]="On Contract Growth"
    ),
    IF(
        AND(
            [TnC Change]="No",
            [Fin Pro]="Yes"
        ),
    "Yes","No"
    )
)
```